# How to skip PreRenderView event when validation has failed?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have a use case in which I want to validate a bunch of viewParams and if I find validation errors, skip the preRenderView event and just display the error messages. Is this possible?

e.g.

```
<f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam id="param1" name="p1" value="#{someBean.param1}" />
            <f:viewParam id="param2" name="p2" value="#{someBean.param2}" />
            <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PostValidateEvent" listener="#{someBean.validateParams}" />
            <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent" listener="#{someBean.viewAction}" />
        </f:metadata>
```

The method validateParams() is used to do multi-field validation and would probably go something like this:

```
    public void validateParams(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
       UIComponent source = event.getComponent();

       Integer value1 = (Integer) ((UIInput) source.findComponent("param1")).getLocalValue();
       Integer value2 = (Integer) ((UIInput) source.findComponent("param2")).getLocalValue();

       boolean valid1 = validOneField(value1);
       boolean valid2 = validOneField(value2);
       boolean valid12 = validBothFields(valid1, valid2);

       if(!valid1);//add facesMessage
       if(!valid2);//add facesMessage
       if(!valid12);//add facesMessage

       if (!valid1 || !valid2 || !valid12)
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }
```

My understanding is that regardless of the forced render response, viewAction() would still be called. I could easily modify viewAction() to take the validation into account but I want to skip it completely due to other reasons (some messy code in that method that I rather not touch, etc.). Is there a way I could completely bypass viewAction() and display the validation error messages?

**Edit: Using BalusC suggestion of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().ValidationFailed()**

i've revised validateParams() to:

```
    public void validateParams(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
       UIComponent source = event.getComponent();

       Integer value1 = (Integer) ((UIInput) source.findComponent("param1")).getLocalValue();
       Integer value2 = (Integer) ((UIInput) source.findComponent("param2")).getLocalValue();

       boolean valid1 = validOneField(value1);
       boolean valid2 = validOneField(value2);
       boolean valid12 = validBothFields(valid1, valid2);

       if(!valid1);//add facesMessage
       if(!valid2);//add facesMessage
       if(!valid12);//add facesMessage

       if (!valid1 || !valid2 || !valid12)
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().ValidationFailed();
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }
```

and the modified viewAction() as follows:

```
public void viewAction(ComponentSystemEvent cse) {
    if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed()) {
        // viewAction() code
    }
}
```

This seems to be working for me now. Hopefully, the view actions in JSF 2.2 won't require me to check whether validation failed since I believe they won't be called at all (the FacesContext.renderResponce() will skip invoke application step, which is where view actions are called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) for that.

```
public void viewAction() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you're manually performing validation instead of using JSF standard `Validator`s for some unclear reason (are you well aware that you can specify a `validator`, `<f:validator>` and `<f:validateXxx>` on `<f:viewParam>`?), you'd need to manually invoke  `FacesContext#validationFailed()` on validation failure.

Comment: You may have meant viewAction(ComponentSystemEvent) instead of validateParams().

Comment: I fixed the method name. I just copied from the code snippet without paying much attention. I was merely answering the quesiton as stated in the title :) The method argument is optional.

Comment: The reason I'm not using standard Validator is because I need to do multiple field validation.